# lower and upper bounds

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

i have the following recurrence relation:

```
T(n) = 2T(n/3) +5(n/6) + n
```

and can't quite figure out the right lower and upper bounds.
for the upper bound I did:

```
T(n) = 2T(n/3) +5T(n/3) +n = 7T(n/6) +n
```

which, according to the master theorem should be: n<sup>log<sub>6</sub>7</sup>

and for the lower bound i did:

```
T(n) = 2T(n/3) +5T(n/3) +n = 7T(n/3) +n
```

which, according to the master theorem should be: n<sup>log<sub>3</sub>7</sup>

however, when solving it that wat i got only partial score as "there are better bounds"
what an i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
T(n)=2*T(n/3)+5*T(n/6)+n

Let
T(n)=c*n^k+o(n^k)

Then
c*n^k+o(n^k)=2*c*(n/3)^k+o((n/3)^k)+5*c*(n/6)^k+o((n/6)^k)+n  

c/6^k*(6^k-2^(k+1)-5)=o(n^k)

k=1.27635...
```

So, T(n) ≃ c*n<sup>1.27635</sup>

T(n) ∈ Θ(n<sup>1.27635</sup>)

Comment: I don't get it. i don't know this formula. can you please explain what you did in here? and is the solution the upper or the lower bound?

Comment: @atlanteh - Both bounds.  Just added Theta-notation.

Comment: thx for the answer, but i don't understand the formula itself, how did you change the t(n) to c*n^k+o(n^k)? and also the last stage:c/6^k*(6^k-2^(k+1)-5)=o(n^k).  
thx a lot!!

Comment: @atlanteh - Sorry, it was my wrong assumption about T(n)=c*n^k+o().  Factors with logarithms may also be present.  Short solution failed.  But long solution exists - substitute T(n) several times in RHS and estimate the bounds.  So, start rewriting T(n/3) as 2T(n/9)+5T(n/18)+n/3 and so on.